# Import csv file to Sqlite database using flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, csv, sqlalchemy

I'm new to databases and sqlalchemy and would like to import data from a csv file to my Sqlite database using flask_sqlalchemy. I have created a model of the table I want to import the data into. What would be the best way to go about this?

I tried using pickle with python dictionaries and that works but since my table now contains more than one row and I'm getting the data from an external source which is already in csv format, I'd like to know how to import the data into the database directly from the csv file.
Here is the code for the model

```
class Subject(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject_name = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)
    qualification = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('qualification.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='Subject', passive_deletes=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this would be to use pandas.
You can read in the CSV with pandas' `read_csv` and dump the same into your DB using `to_sql`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV)

# modify the df columns here to suit your DB schema

df.to_sql(NAME_OF_TABLE, con=db.engine, if_exists = "append", index=False)
```

Comment: Hey, trying to implement this, where do I pass the name of the database here? I've modified the question to include the structure of the app.

Comment: Hi, the second argument in the function `to_sql` takes the DB connection. In this case, this is the same as the DB that you've configured for your Flask app.